# Is the result of an lvalue-to-rvalue conversion of a non-const expression constant?

Tags: c++

I am trying to figure whether or not the following two statements both ODR-use the variable "x" (`int x=2`).

1. `int c = x;`
2. `int y = x+12;`
3. `int* z = &x;`

So is my confusion:

I have [read that](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition#ODR-use) if *not* "applying lvalue-to-rvalue conversion to x yields a constant expression that doesn't invoke non-trivial functions" then it is ODR-used. I know that the third statement does ODR-uses `x` but the first and the second, nah not entirely sure...

Regarding statement 1: Is it correct that this statement does not ODR-use `x`?

Regarding statement 2: It it with respect to this particular statement that I am looking at the criteria above. An rvalue-to-lvalue conversion is applied to `x` to satisfy the requirements of the + operator but does this yield a constant expression? From my understanding, it does, since it would yield the rvalue `2`, which I guess never changes and thus is *constant*. So what I find it quite confusing that a constant expression is an expression that is constant, which would make the result of the conversion a constant expression from what I have learnt. The problem just is that the variable `x` is *not* constant, so it would be odd to me that the result of something involving this suddenly is *constant*...

Comment: Your reading is back to front - it says that a variable is ODR-used **unless** that predicate is true.  So yes, `x` is ODR-used in both #1 and #2.

Comment: @OliverCharlesworth Ahh true that.. But that does really change the state of my confusion... I still do totally understand whether or not statement 2 ODR-uses ´x´ because of my confusion about whether or not the result of the conversion is a constant expression AND if statement 1 really does not ODR-use ´x´. So my question is still valid, I guess. The question has been edited a little - just added a "not" :)

Comment: It would depend on the scope of `x = 2`, however within any scope it would be odr-used so your 1) is incorrect. That depends on scope of `y` and it could or could not be ODR used. As it's written it's not, but if `y` was a global then yes! and not only that it would be different from `int y = 1 + x + 11`

Comment: not sure who downvoted it but can you explain why you downvoted it? it's a reasonable question for [so]

Comment: And 3 isn't even a legal statement, perhaps meant "int * z = &x;"?

Comment: @SoronelHaetir - Maybe I'm missing something, but that seems to be the same as what the OP already wrote...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Constant expression* is a [term of art](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.const).

Long story short, if an expression uses the value of a variable, and the variable is

1. not a reference
2. not `constexpr`, and
3. not `const` integer or enum

... then the expression cannot be a constant expression.

Comment: Alright, thank you! So the cv-qualification of the result of the conversion is dependent on the qualification of the object involved, right? Also, if the result is the rvalue "5", how can this then NOT be a constant expression - you cannot change it, right?

Comment: I really would love to know if you could answer my question in the comment above... It would put an end to my wonder :)

Comment: @step 1. Sometimes, but that isn't directly related to the definition of constant expression. 2. Because that's not the definition of constant expression.